# Function $f(z)$ with equal limit point of zeros $z_n$ and poles $p_n$ $\lim z_n=\lim p_n<\infty$

Tags: complex-analysis

Is there an analogous Weierstrass factorization of such a function?

$$f(z)=z^me^{g(z)}\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{E_{N_n}(z/z_n)}{E_{D_n}(z/p_n)}\qquad \lim z_n=\lim p_n=x\in\mathbb{C}$$

and if so what are its convergence/meromorphicity properties? My expectation is that $f(z)$ is meromorphic for $|z|<|x|$ but I am having a hard time proving this. Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: Poles of $f$ are zeroes of $1/f$ so if you know how to construct (non constant) analytic functions with zeroes at $x_n$ and $p_n$ respectively, take their ratio which is obviously meromorphic

Comment: Isn't it true that a holomorphic function with a limit point of zeros is identically zero? I think something subtle must happen when the zeros and poles both approach the same point $x$.

Comment: No if the point is on the boundary; one easily can construct holomorphic functions on more or less any domain with zeroes going to the boundary; of course those functions cannot be entire or more generally holomorphic at the limit point of the zeroes

Comment: Okay, then my thoughts would be that a function $f$ with just a limit point of zeros with a Weierstrass product representation can only converge for $|z|<|x|$. A function of the type I described in the question could have better convergence properties I think.

Comment: You cannot construct weirstrasss product directly when the zeroes have a limit point, but you can construct modified such